# Redirecting multiple domains/URLs to one, canonical domain exclude certain Subs or re-word the REWRITE

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have checked the Apache's rewrite guide on how to redirect non-www requests to www requests:

> If the domain (any domain) is not exactly my.example.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^abc\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://abc.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

this is working for the main redirect but is causing a problem with other subs-domains that are not meant to redirect.

How do you exclude certain Subs or re-word the REWRITE.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`How do you exclude certain Subs`

You can tweak regex further in `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(abc|exclude1|exclude2)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://abc.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```